# Behaviour of Generic Type in Java

Tags: java, class, generics

Stack class

```
public class Stack
{
public void push(LinkedList ll) {

}
```

LinkedList class

```
class LinkedList<Item>
{
 private class Node<Element>
 {
    private Element value ;
    private Node<Element> next;
 }
 Node(Element value, Node<Element> ref) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = ref;
    }
}
```

I have my main method in class Stack , in it I have made an object of class Stack and and object of class LinkedList and I am calling push method.
What I dont understand is that If I use `(LinkedList<Type> ll)` as argument compiler is showing an error:

```
cannot find symbol
    public void push(LinkedList<Item> ll) {
                                ^
  symbol:   class Item
  location: class Stack
```

Why is this error occuring ang why it works fine if i use

```
public void push(LinkedList ll)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the declaration of `LinkedList`, `Item` is the name of a type parameter. It only has direct meaning within the `LinkedList` class itself.

When you're declaring your `push` method and *using* `LinkedList`, you'd specify a type *argument*, i.e. the element type of the linked list. For example, this would be fine:

```
public void push(LinkedList<String> ll)
```

... but `Item` isn't a meaningful identifier.

Now as an alternative, you could make your `Stack` class generic too:

```
public class Stack<Item>
{
    public void push(LinkedList<Item> ll) { ... }    
}
```

... but you should be aware that the fact that both the `LinkedList` and `Stack` declarations use a type parameter called `Item` is effectively a coincidence. It would be exactly equivalent to write:

```
public class Stack<T>
{
    public void push(LinkedList<T> ll) { ... }    
}
```